# Python - Automate parameter change in loop

Tags: python

First things first, I'm new to Python and the following info may contain bad coding and incorrect names.

I have the following Endpoint example to create a key using an HTTPS API:

```
client.newkey('123abc', [
    {
        "name": "key_0",
        "description": "Python created"
    }
    ]
)
```

This code is submitted through an API which will, then, use the `123abc` parameter to create and assign that new key online using the said name and decription.

I need to automate the creation and assignment of multiple keys (lets say finishing with 100) that use different names only (eg. key_0, key_1, key_2, ...) that aren't automatically assigned by the API (so a simple loop for said above code won't do) and, thus, I would need to insert a `x+1` variable for the value `key_` in `name` for every execution after the first one or similar.

My thoughts are towards a code that will check in a variable how many keys are already present in the code (x) and sum 1 for the next one (x+1), then, use a `newkey` template but inserting the results after `key_`, in a loop.

I have checked [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which seems quite close to what I need but I'm still quite off on how should I apply it.

I tried to make my information as clear as possible with my knowledge considered.
Thank you!

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, but to me is sounds like it would be closer to a dictionary comprehension than a list comprehension.

Comment: Hello John, I understand being unclear with my experience considered, you have my apologies. The said code is a keys endpoint for an API, in that case to create new ones. If you have any questions please keep me informed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re trying to generate an arbitrary list of keys (like key_0, key_1, etc) you can use the following code:

```
keys = [f’key_{x}’ for x in range(10)]

for k in keys:
    client.newKey(‘123abc’, [
{
    "name": k,
    "description": "Python created"
}
])
```

Also, it’s probably a good idea to check if you can create keys in bulk to avoid making several API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think the part you're missing is how to parameterize the `name` key.  I'll break it down:

```
cnt = len(client)   # ... or whatever you've named your list of dicts
key = "key_" + str(cnt)
client.newkey('123abc', [
    {
        "name": key,
        "description": "Python created"
    }
    ]
)
```

With that string concatenation, you can embed this in a loop, or whatever you need.  If you're adding a lot of these at once, a `for` is most likely what you want, such as ...

```
for cnt in range(len(client), some_limit):
    # re-use above code, except for the first `cnt =` line
```

Comment: Thank you for this info Prune, it makes sense. I'll take some time to study it and if I have any questions I'll let you know